# Add Javascript to an usercontrol in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have an `UserControl`, it is a `ToolTip`.

.**ascx** :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucTooltip.ascx.cs" Inherits="Portail.formulaires.ucTooltip" debug="true"%>


<div id="dhtmltooltip" style="z-index:9999999999; display:inline-block;">
  <div id="dhtmltooltip_title">

  </div>
  <div id="dhtmltooltip_content">

  </div>
</div>
```

.**cs** :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace Portail.formulaires
    {
        public partial class ucTooltip : System.Web.UI.UserControl
        {
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
              Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("Hint", Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/hint.js"));
           }
        }
    }
```

This control is really simple, I simply add a reference and the control to the page I want to use it :

```
<%@ Register src="Controles/ucTooltip.ascx" tagname="ucTooltip" tagprefix="ucTT" %>
...
<ucTT:ucTooltip ID="tooltip" runat="server" />
...
```

So, the control is loaded and the script is added to the page.

But I am trying to do something more elaborate. Given that I have a lot control that need a tooltip, I decided to add an `Event`(it will show and hide the tooltip) to my usercontrol's base. All the usercontrol is use inside my main page (The tooltip is accessible from this page).

First, I have tried something like that :

```
protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "alert('d')");
}
```

On the control's base page load, I had an attribute to throw the event "OnMouseOver" to the control.

But it don't work, I am very confuse why...

Comment: look and see where the attribute is being added in the dom

Comment: Also put a break point on Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "alert('d')"); and make sure its being fired

Comment: I did the verefication ,and it is being fired. But it look like the attributes is not being added...

Comment: Try @Luis Miguel's suggestion and see if that helps

Comment: Also can you post a copy of your DOM ?

Comment: What do you mean @MicahArmantrout

Comment: if Luis's answer doesn't help Post a copy of your browser source

Comment: can you let us see your dom / page source ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a `UserControl` has an `Attributes` property, it doesn't actually do anything. Instead, you need to put the `onmouseover` attribute on an element inside your .ascx markup. For example:

```
<div id="dhtmltooltip" style="z-index:9999999999; display:inline-block;" onmouseover="alert('d')">
```

If you need to add the attribute dynamically, then make the `<div>` a `runat="server"` control so that you can access its `Attributes` property from the code-behind file:

```
dhtmltooltip.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "alert('d')");
```

Comment: @VincP.: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: No, I am getting an exception, it say object reference is null. I tried to find a solution, but it look like you can't access the div if you declare it in the base user control...

Comment: @VincP.: Did you add `runat="server"` to the `<div>`? Also, how did you declare it in the base user control?

Comment: yes it have runat="server", in the ascx : <div id="test" runat="server"></div> , but when I am trying to add an attribute to this Div, the exception throw because the object reference is null : test = null. It look like I can't access the div. This how I create the link to the base control : public partial class ucMemo : ucControl

Comment: Was the `protected HtmlGenericControl test;` field generated by the designer, or did you add it yourself? If you're inheriting user controls, could there be two different `test` fields?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

`Attributes.Add("OnMouseOver", "javascript:alert('d')");`